# Laravel Relationship in between 3 tables

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have three tables

1. partners
2. Partner_cities
3. cities

**Partners Table** -

```
id     | Name
------ | ------
1      | Oracle
2      | TCS
```

**Partner_Cities Table**

```
id     | partner_id   | city_id
------ | ------
1      | 1            | 2
2      | 1            | 3
```

**Cities Table**

```
id     | Name
------ | ------
1      | Delhi
2      | Mumbai
```

Now I want the relationship in between **partners** and **cities** table.

My Partner Model has

```
public function cities(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class, 'partner_cities')  ;
}
```

and City Model has -

```
public function partners(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Partner::class, 'partner_cities');
}
```

I am getting  -

```
ErrorException in ObjectDataRow.php line 21:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name
```

Comment: Where you used `$name`??

Comment: Can you post your controller that are using either of these relationships? We have no idea where is this `$name` coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You partner model should be more like:

```php
public function cities(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class);
}
```

And your City Model like:

```php
public function partners(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Partner::class);
}
```

Rename your partner_cities table to city_partner (following Laravel's naming conventions) and remove the id column.

You can read more about many-many relationships in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

Answer (score 0):

Partners and Cities is **many to many** relationchip already, so you have the Partner_Cities as **pivot** table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Check this

1. One to Many

```
    public function partners() {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
    }

    public function cities() {
        return $this->hasMany(Partner::class);
    }
```

2. Many to Many

```
    public function partners() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(City::class);
    }

    public function cities() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Partner::class);
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the question can you please have a look again @gbail